# Appending df lines into another df based on its index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df1`:

```
              col1    col2   col3  col4  col5
        A       3       4     1      2    1
        B       2       1     2      3    1
        C       2       3     4      2    1
```

On the other hand I have the `df2`:

```
              type    col1    col2   col3
        j      A       0.5     0.7    0.1
        k      B       0.2     0.3    0.9 
        l      A       0.5     0.3    0.2
        m      C       0.8     0.7    0.1
        n      A       0.3     0.3    0.2
        o      B       0.1     0.7    0.3
```

Given the column `type` in `df2` I would like to generate like a pivot table like this:

```
             col1    col2   col3  col4  col5
    A          3       4     1      2    1
        j     0.5     0.7    0.1
        l     0.5     0.3    0.2
        n     0.3     0.3    0.2
    B          2       1     2      3    1
        k     0.2     0.3    0.9 
        o     0.1     0.7    0.3
    C          2       3     4      2    1
        m     0.8     0.7    0.1
```

Is there premade function in pandas I could used to append each line in `df2` below its corresponding index in `df1`?

Sorry I do not include my try , but I have no idea on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Those empty cells are `NaN`s?

Comment: For the case would be `Nan`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `MultiIndex` here. You should *not* use `NaN` indices as shown in your desired result: the label lacks meaning. One idea is to use a non-letter indicator such as `0`:

```
# set index as (type, current_index) for df2
df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index(['type', 'index']).sort_index()

# reassign index as (type, 0) for df1
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, 0) for i in df1.index])

# concatenate df1 and df2
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

print(res)

     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
A 0   3.0   4.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
  j   0.5   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
  l   0.5   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
  n   0.3   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
B 0   2.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   1.0
  k   0.2   0.3   0.9   NaN   NaN
  o   0.1   0.7   0.3   NaN   NaN
C 0   2.0   3.0   4.0   2.0   1.0
  m   0.8   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and `sort_index` specifying `na_position='first'`

```
pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), 
         df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'type'}),
         'outer')\
.set_index(['type', 'index'])\
.sort_index(na_position='first')

                col1   col2   col3  col4   col5
type    index                   
A       NaN     3.0    4.0    1.0   2.0    1.0
        j       0.5    0.7    0.1   NaN    NaN
        l       0.5    0.3    0.2   NaN    NaN
        n       0.3    0.3    0.2   NaN    NaN
B       NaN     2.0    1.0    2.0   3.0    1.0
        k       0.2    0.3    0.9   NaN    NaN
        o       0.1    0.7    0.3   NaN    NaN
C       NaN     2.0    3.0    4.0   2.0    1.0
        m       0.8    0.7    0.1   NaN    NaN
```

As highlighted by @jpp, in the docs for [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) it says that

> na_position : {‘first’, ‘last’}, default ‘last’
>   first puts NaNs at the beginning, last puts NaNs at the end. **Not implemented for MultiIndex.**

even though it actually seems to *be, indeed, implemented*.

However, if you think this behavior could be inconsistent, an alternative is to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first, and just then setting the index. In [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) Docs, no such not implemented warning exists.

```
pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), 
         df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'type'}), 
         'outer')\
.sort_values(['type', 'index'], na_position='first')\
.set_index(['type', 'index'])
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), `na_position='first'` is not implemented for `MultiIndex`. Why does it work here, or are the docs wrong?

Comment: @jpp Good question. Definitely has an impact on this code, i.e. changing `first` to `last` *actually changes* `NaN`s from first position to last. Added an observation for that, thanks for pointing! ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### Similar to [**@jpp**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52837362/2336654)

```
d2 = df2.rename_axis('k').set_index('type', append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
d1 = df1.set_index(np.zeros(len(df1), str), append=True).rename_axis(['type', 'k'])

d1.append(d2).sort_index()

        col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
type k                              
A        3.0   4.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
     j   0.5   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
     l   0.5   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
     n   0.3   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
B        2.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   1.0
     k   0.2   0.3   0.9   NaN   NaN
     o   0.1   0.7   0.3   NaN   NaN
C        2.0   3.0   4.0   2.0   1.0
     m   0.8   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
```

---

#### Alternate

```
df1.rename_axis('type').assign(k='').set_index('k', append=True).append(
    df2.rename_axis('k').set_index('type', append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
).sort_index()

        col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
type k                              
A        3.0   4.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
     j   0.5   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
     l   0.5   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
     n   0.3   0.3   0.2   NaN   NaN
B        2.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   1.0
     k   0.2   0.3   0.9   NaN   NaN
     o   0.1   0.7   0.3   NaN   NaN
C        2.0   3.0   4.0   2.0   1.0
     m   0.8   0.7   0.1   NaN   NaN
```